# Why the starvation of lower-priority threads in OS X or iOS may block other threads and create performance bottlenecks?

Tags: multithreading

In the **Threading Programming Guide** that is a document of Apple mentioned:

> Increasing the priorities of some threads also increases the likelihood of starvation among lower-priority threads. If your application contains high-priority and low-priority threads that must interact with each other, the starvation of lower-priority threads may block other threads and create performance bottlenecks.

I could understand first half of above statement, but I could not understand the rest. So I come here to find answer and hope someone could explain for me who is a pretty newer in Thread.

Comment: This is more of a general scheduling topic rather than being specific to Apple technologies. Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)

Comment: @KennethBruno Thanks, I'm reading now! :)